# Is it better to return a view from a controller action, or to use ajax requests and redirect to a url?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm currently developing a web application using C# with the MVC framework and I've stumbled upon an interesting question.

I was programming some server-side validation and found that I needed to make an ajax request to a controller, make that controller return an URL, and then use javascript to redirect to that URL. This was needed in this particular case since I was working with model validation in a partial view(inside a modal).

My question is: Is it better to return a view from a controller(Actionresult/Viewresult)?

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddLeverancier(Leverancier leverancier)
{

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

or redirect to a URL from Javascript?

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteAllLeveranciers()
{

    return Json(Url.Action("Index", "Leverancier"));
}
```

**javascript.js**

```
        self.baseManager.DoAjaxRequest("POST", self.baseURL + "/DeleteAllLeveranciers", null, function (data) {
        window.location.href = data;
        self.baseManager.HideModal("deleteAllLeveranciersModal");
    });
```

Is there any risk/performance issue related to this? Does it make any significant difference?

Thank you in advance,

Mick

Comment: If you defer the redirect to javascript then that means you are relying on the browser of the user to do the redirection. That will also mean that you could give the user a freehand to "manipulate" the resulting url. When you return to view, you are sending a result already, without letting the user control it.

Comment: Redirecting after an AJAX request entirely defeats the point of AJAX. Just do a normal form POST at that point and throw away the AJAX. As far as view vs. redirect goes, it's not an either-or situation. There's times to use both and you can't really sub one for the other. All this boils down to simply building an application properly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That's not even true. It can be used to do something with the data returned before reloading the page, or to work with modal forms by posting the form without closing the modal window. By doing this you can verify if the server-side validation went through well without closing te modal, and if the server-side validation succeeded you can reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

It is all depend on how fluent you want at client-side.

In ***ASP.NET MVC***, I *personally* like to use full post-back for ***HttpPost***, as I like strongly typed server-side language for unit tests and integrated tests. It is not easy to unit test JavaScript embedded inside html. *(If I use Angular, it is totally different story.)*

For simple ***HttpGet*** which doesn't require any validation, I like to use Ajax.